# Is there a way to check a dataframe against a single value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
  
# Creating a dict of lists  
data = {'Name':["Akash", "Geeku", "Pankaj", "Sumitra","Ramlal"], 
       'Branch':["B.Tech", np.nan, "BCA", "B.Tech", "BCA"], 
       'Score':["80","90","60", "30", "B.Tech"], 
       'Result': ["Pass","Pass","Pass","Fail","Fail"]} 
  
# creating a dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df
```

df1:

[image]

Then I want to check the dataframe against a value like 'B.Tech' that can be anywhere in the df. And return some df like this one below.

df2:

[image]

Then I want to get a list, where the value would be based on the first 4 boolean value, e.g. if any value in first 4 columns contains one+ True, the new column would be True, otherwise False

For this case, the result I want is *[True, False, False, False, True]*

Sorry I am new to pandas, I wonder if Pandas provides an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it in one go:

`(df == "B.Tech").sum(axis=1).astype(bool)`

To explain:

`df == "B.Tech"` returns a DataFrame the same shape as your original but just containing True/False values as to whether the value is equal to "B.Tech"

`.sum(axis=1)` sums the boolean values by row, interpreting True as 1 and False as 0.

`.astype(bool)` converts the results of the sum back into boolean, where anything greater than 0 becomes True, and 0 becomes False.

#### Update:

Alternatively as Ch3steR pointed out you can replace the last part with [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), as in:

`(df == "B.Tech").any(axis=1)`

Comment: `.any(1)` instead of `.sum(axis=1).astype(book)`?

Comment: The solution returns a pandas.Series, so to get the row numbers where the result is True you can do: `s = (df == "B.Tech").any(axis=1); s[s].index`